# Repeatedly creating instances of an object without repeating code

Tags: python, list, loops, variable-assignment

I want to make a game where the player clicks on ducks using the `pygame` module in Python. I want to have 15 ducks, but I don't want to copy code for instantiating a duck and assigning it to a variable 15 times. My current code is below, and `"eend"` is the name I'm using for ducks:

```
eend = Actor('eend')
eend._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend._surf, (50, 50))
eend.pos = 425, 300

eend1 = Actor('eend')
eend1._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend1._surf, (50, 50))
eend1.pos = 425, 300

eend2 = Actor('eend')
eend2._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend2._surf, (50, 50))
eend2.pos = 425, 300

eend3 = Actor('eend')
eend3._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend3._surf, (50, 50))
eend3.pos = 425, 300

eend4 = Actor('eend')
eend4._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend4._surf, (50, 50))
eend4.pos = 425, 300

eend5 = Actor('eend')
eend5._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend5._surf, (50, 50))
eend5.pos = 425, 300

eend6 = Actor('eend')
eend6._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend6._surf, (50, 50))
eend6.pos = 425, 300

eend7 = Actor('eend')
eend7._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend7._surf, (50, 50))
eend7.pos = 425, 300

eend8 = Actor('eend')
eend8._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend8._surf, (50, 50))
eend8.pos = 425, 300

eend9 = Actor('eend')
eend9._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend9._surf, (50, 50))
eend9.pos = 425, 300

eend10 = Actor('eend')
eend10._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend10._surf, (50, 50))
eend10.pos = 425, 300

eend11 = Actor('eend')
eend11._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend11._surf, (50, 50))
eend11.pos = 425, 300

eend12 = Actor('eend')
eend12._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend12._surf, (50, 50))
eend12.pos = 425, 300

eend13 = Actor('eend')
eend13._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend13._surf, (50, 50))
eend13.pos = 425, 300

eend14 = Actor('eend')
eend14._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend14._surf, (50, 50))
eend14.pos = 425, 300
```

What is a good way to create multiple instances of the class `Actor` without repeating the code 15 times?

Comment: You should really learn lists and loops.... start here maybe: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Comment: You could write a for-loop and put your Actors in a list instead of  14 similar variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that creates ducks for you, and then create a list of ducks (instead of keeping them as separate variable names).

```
def create_duck(name='eend', scale=(50, 50), pos=(425, 300)):
    eend = Actor(name)
    eend._surf = pygame.transform.scale(eend8._surf, scale)
    eend.pos = pos
    return eend

eends = []
for i in range(14):
    eends.append(create_duck())
```

You can also have this function as a [class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod) in your `Actor` class

Comment: its nice but then i get this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python programs\eendjes vangen\eend.py", line 15, in <module>
    eend.append(create_duck())
  File "D:\python programs\eendjes vangen\eend.py", line 8, in create_duck
    eend = Actor(eend)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'eend' referenced before assignment

Comment: @ibon `eend = Actor(eend)` should be `eend = Actor(name)`